# How is it possible to configure my app that shell links created of my application get the icon of cmd.exe?

Tags: windows, cmd, icons

My application uses `ExtractIcon` to extract the icon of `cmd.exe`. So far everything seems to work.

But if I create a shell link of my application the shell link  will have the default application icon. I know how to associate the icon of `cmd.exe` manually to a shell link by using `IShellLink::SetIconLocation` (with the path of `cmd.exe` as `pszIconPath` and 0 as `iIcon`)

Now I want to change my application so that every shell link created of my application automatically receives `cmd.exe,0` as icon.
I would like to know how.

Comment: IMO the tag `cmd` isn't relevant here, your programming language/environment seems more important.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you have a choice, if anyone creates a `.lnk` by copying and pasting as link the default icon will be choosen.
Otherwise, if you/the app creates the link you can do as your layout suggests.

Optionally check/modify present `.lnk` files with your app as targetpath with a PowerShell script like this

```
$ShortcutPath   = Join-Path ([Environment]::GetFolderPath('Desktop')) "YourApp.lnk"
$TargetPath     = "C:\Program Files (x86)\YourApp\YourApp.exe"
$IconLocation   = "C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe"
$IconArrayIndex = 0

$Shell = New-Object -comObject WScript.Shell
$Shortcut = $Shell.CreateShortcut($ShortcutPath)
$Shortcut.TargetPath = $TargetPath
$Shortcut.IconLocation = "$IconLocation, $IconArrayIndex"
$Shortcut.Save()
```

[image]